# Consistent deployment for ejabberd cluster in cloud?

Tags: ejabberd

From the docs @ http://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/guide/clustering/#clustering-setup

> Adding a node into the cluster is done by starting a new ejabberd node within the same network, and running a command from a cluster node. On second node for example, as ejabberd is already started, run the following command as the ejabberd daemon user, using the ejabberdctl script: `ejabberdctl join_cluster 'ejabberd@first'`

How does this translate into deployment in the cloud- where instances can (hopefully) be shutdown/restarted based on a consistent image and behind a load balancer?

Can all of them, including the initial instance, use "example.com" as "first" in the example above (assuming "example.com" is setup in DNS to point to the cloud load balancer)?

Or must the first instance not attempt to join a cluster, and subsequent ones all use the ip address of that initial instance instead of "first" (and if this is the case- does it get wacky if that initial instance goes down)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can all of them, including the initial instance, use "example.com" as "first" in the example above (assuming "example.com" is setup in DNS to point to the cloud load balancer)?

No, the node name parameter is the node name of an Erlang ejabberd node. It should even more be on the internal Amazon network, not the public one, so it should not rely on a central DNS. It must be a name of an Erlang node as the newly started node with connect to the existing node to share the same "cluster schema" and do an initial sync of the data.

So, the deployment is done as follow:

- first instance does not need to join a cluster indeed as there is no cluster schema to share.
- New instance can use the node name of any other node of the cluster. It means they will add themselves to the ejabberd cluster schema. It means ejabberd knows that users can be on any node of this cluster. You can point to any running node in the cluster to add a new one, as they are all equivalent (there is no master).
- You still need to configure the load balancer to balance traffic to public XMPP port on all nodes.

You only need to perform the cluster config for each once for each extra cluster node. The configuration with all the node is kept locally, so when you stop and restart a node, it will then automatically rejoined the cluster after it has been properly set up.

Comment: OK- got it... does it matter which node is used to connect to (i.e. any difference to re-use the same one vs. spreading it out for additional nodes) and also, once they are connected- does it break if the original one goes down? (I'm hoping the two problems are related, and the answer to both is "no" since the connection is just to get them in the door... but just to be sure).

Comment: Assuming those both are "no", I've continued the setup discussion in more detail here: https://www.ejabberd.im/forum/25020/consistent-deployment-ejabberd-cluster-cloud

Comment: This is correct. You can point to any running node in the cluster to add a new one, as they are all equivalent (there is no master) and you only need to perform the cluster config for each once for each extra cluster node. The configuration with all the node is kept locally, so when you stop and restart a node, it will then automatically rejoined the cluster after it has been properly set up (I updated main answer to be clearer for future readers).

Comment: Wow, that is awesome, you've thought of everything! :D